# how to download multi files in mvc4 with one actionlink?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

action:

```
public ActionResult Download(string filename)
    {
        var filenames = filename.Split(',').Distinct();
        var dirSeparator = Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;
        foreach (var f in filenames)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(f)) continue;
            var path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Uploads" + dirSeparator + f;
            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(path)) continue;
            return new BinaryContentResult
                       {
                           FileName = f,
                           ContentType = "application/octet-stream",
                           Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path)
                       };
        }
        return View("Index");
    }
```

BinaryContentResult method:

```
public class BinaryContentResult : ActionResult
{
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public byte[] Content { get; set; }
    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        context.HttpContext.Response.ClearContent();
        context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = ContentType;
        context.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FileName);
        context.HttpContext.Response.BinaryWrite(Content);
        context.HttpContext.Response.End();
    }
}
```

view:

```
 @{
                foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                @Html.ActionLink("Link","Index", "FileUpload", new { postid = item.PostId })
                }
            }
```

but actionlink just download one(fisrt) file.

Comment: Why are you re-inventing a slower version of `FileStreamResult`?

Comment: HTTP does not support that.

Comment: how to use `FileStreamResult`?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492593.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to zip all the files into a single file and then return this zip to the client. Also your code has a huge flaw : you are loading the entire file contents in memory before returning it to the client: `System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path)` instead of just using the `FileStreamResult` that's designed exactly for that purpose. You seem to have reinvented some wheels with that `BinaryContentResult` class.

So:

```
public ActionResult Download(string filename)
{
    var filenames = filename.Split(',').Distinct();
    string zipFile = Zip(filenames);
    return File(zip, "application/octet-stream", "download.zip");
}

private string Zip(IEnumerable<string> filenames)
{
    // here you could use any available zip library, such as SharpZipLib
    // to create a zip file containing all the files and return the physical
    // location of this zip on the disk
}
```